# jQuery selector for labeled radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQ selector for radio like this:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click change', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    //todo: do some stuff with input

});

<div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="main" value="1" >Number 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="main" value="2" >Number 2</label>
</div>
```

but how to change selector if I have some radios labeled and no-labeled?

Comment: try input:radio as selector instead of 'input[type=radio]'

Comment: How does an element outside your selector change anything? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Your current selector is not using the label at all.  Label vs no label, your current selector doesn't care

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not using the label

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click change', function() {
    var el = $(this).val();
        alert(el); //check result you can read all checkbox value if in label or instead label
});
```

```html
<div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="main" value="1" >Number 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="main" value="2" >Number 2</label>
</div>
<input type="radio" name="main" value="3" >Number 3
```